# El componente MatDatepicker de Material me devuelve un día menos que la fecha seleccionada

Tags: angular, angular-material, material

El componente MatDatePicker me devuelve las fechas con un día menos que el seleccionado.
Si selecciono "11/02/2018" el formulario me devuelve: "2018-02-10T22:00:00.000Z".
Llevo días buscando la solución, he seguido las instrucciones de la página oficial de Material... Y no consigo solucionarlo.

Utilizo Angular 7 ( Tambien é probado con la versión 6).
Tengo un modulo "shared" con todos los componentes de material que utilizo:

Alli pretendo seleccionar el idioma de los MatDatePicket y que use fechas UTC para tratar de arreglar el problema
Me selecciona el idioma correctamente pero siempre me devuelve un día menos.

**mat.module.ts.**

```
import { MatMomentDateModule, 
     MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS,
     MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS,
     MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { DateAdapter, 
     MAT_DATE_FORMATS, 
     MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';

.........

{ provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
{ provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS},
{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'gl'},
{ provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true } },
```

**en el componente:**

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex>
  <input matInput
        [readonly]="true"
        [matDatepicker]="ELEPRO_DATA"
        class="form-control"
        id="ELEPRO_DATA"
        formControlName="ELEPRO_DATA"
        placeholder="Data">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle 
        matSuffix 
        [for]="ELEPRO_DATA"
        *ngIf="!readOnly"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #ELEPRO_DATA></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: cuando dices me devuelve, a que te refieres, es lo que llega al servidor o lo que muestra el compionente?

Comment: En pantalla me presenta bien la fecha, pero al formulario (es reactivo) me la envia mal.

Comment: tengo que implementar esto mismo estos días, comenzare a hacerlo y te comento como me va, consulta este comportamiento es siempre o sucede solo aveces.

Comment: podrias intentar usar algo como esto si no lo haz hecho aun para ver la hora correcta. moment.utc('2016-01-01').format(), cambiar la fecha por tu entrada de fechas.

Comment: que zona horaria tienes? sorry tanta pregunta, quiero entender tu problema para no tenerlo en el futuro :)

Comment: Estoy en España

Comment: Podrias compartir el componente. creo que no esta del todo mal lo que hace tu formulario. ya que esta mostrandote el horario de españa calculado a UTC por lo que estaria bien que te muestre un dia menos. quizas lo que debes hacer es tomar estos datos de otra forma que no te formatee el valor a utc. el datepicker me refiero, tambien seria util que agregaras un log en la consola con lo que te muestra el objeto moment de la fecha.

Answer (score 1):

Ese error es algo propio de javascript, cuando envía la fecha con 00:00:00 se formatea con el día anterior, aunque no entiendo si es por la zona horaria o como pasa ese detalle, recomiendo si necesitan persistir los datos o traer los datos formatearlo todo con la clase Date de javascript ya que matpicker solo utiliza funcionalidades de js para formatear fechas por lo que veo.

A mi me paso lo mismo pero al momento de persistir lo datos porque los necesitaba con dato por defecto y me mostraba el dia anterior entonces me toco algo así:

```
this.filtersFormGroup = this.fb.group({
  date_picker: [new Date(), Validators.required],
});
```

O tambien se puede con moment de esta manera

```
this.filtersFormGroup = this.fb.group({
  date_picker: [moment().toDate(), Validators.required],
});
```

Supongo que eso lo puede aplicar al contrario para tomar la fecha

Answer (score 0):

quizas si pusieras el ejemplo completo seria mas facil replicar tu error y por que te da mal la fecha.

te dejo un ejemplo que implemente hoy y la idea es que consulte una api, revise el request que genera y todo ok. espero te sirva de ayuda, si no podemos seguir revisando. tambien uso reactive forms.

esto es un extracto del proyecto que estoy trabajando por lo que no lo pude probar de forma isolada, si esto no funciona podria crear un proyecto especial solo para la prueba. pero funciona junto al proyecto.

por lo que veo tenemos unas diferencias, probe con la opcion de UTC true y obtengo el resultado correcto tambien.

**Clase**

```
import { Moment } from 'moment';    

export interface ClienteFiltroModel {
      nombreCliente: string;
      idTipoCliente: number;
      identificacion: string;
      idTipoIdentificacion: number;
      fechaDesde: Moment;
      fechaHasta: Moment;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dpHasta" placeholder="Fecha Creación Hasta" formControlName="fechaHasta">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dpHasta"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #dpHasta ></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

**Modulo**

```
import {
  MatDatepickerModule,
  DateAdapter,
  MAT_DATE_LOCALE,
  MAT_DATE_FORMATS
} from '@angular/material';
import { MatMomentDateModule, MomentDateAdapter, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'es-CL' },
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS}
]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

request generado:

GET http://localhost:50652/api/clientes?nombreCliente=&idTipoCliente=&identificacion=&idTipoIdentificacion=&fechaDesde=2018-11-02T03:00:00.000Z&fechaHasta=2018-11-24T03:00:00.000Z HTTP/1.1

**Actualizacion**

al parecer como lo comentaste varias veces tu problema es de la zona horaria. una solucion si el offset no es un dato importante para tu formulario. es dejar este de lado de la siguiente forma.

(fecha-tipo-moment).format('LLL')

Quedo atento, Saludos!!

Comment: Me fijo que en realidad a ti te está pasando lo mismo que a mí. A tí te devuelve 2018-11-24T03:00:00.000Z cuando debería ser 2018-11-24T00:00:00.000Z. A mí me descuenta un día y me pone las 23:00--> 2018-11-11T23:00:00.000Z. Ahora mismo son las 18:26 del día 12. Seguramente depende de la zona horaria en la que estemos.

Answer (score 0):

[manu_rit]

He copiado la configuración de tu modulo que tenía alguna pequeña diferencia con la que esta usando. Y todo funciona igual.

El proceso sucede así:

Formulario de registro nuevo, selecciono la fecha de hoy y en el input aparece correctamente, pero en el formulario aparece mal, como se ve en la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Grabo el registro y si entro a editarlo me descuenta un día más, tanto en el input como en el dato del formulario. Imagen al abrir la pantalla de edición:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo porqué me mete la hora 23:00, supongo que por el uso horario, pero creo que descuenta un día por esa razón.

Un saludo.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**
Me rindo. No he conseguido que el datePicker me devuelva bien el valor.
He decidido hacer un hack antes de enviar el formulario a la base de datos y con esto funciona correctamente:

```js
    const data = moment(this.formulario.get('DATA').value).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    this.formulario.get('DATA').setValue(data);
```

Comment: de donde sacas la información que muestras en pantalla, es decir la info del objeto que muestras en el ejemplo? me muestras el comando que estas usando para eso si es consola.

Comment: y como almacenas los datos de la fecha.

Comment: Viste el comentario que te hice en el post que está al final? Creo que tambien tienes el mismo problema que yo pero no lo notas

Comment: yo creo que no, el horario que muestras es transformado a UTC por eso vez el 23. tengo la impresion que si es un tema de zona horaria pero quiero poder replicar tu error. jamas me va a devolver solo 0 en el tiempo por lo que te comente.

Comment: Estoy utilizando formularios reactivos. Mientras programo pongo esto en el html del componente para ver que valor tiene en cada momento: <pre>Formulario válido: {{ formulario.valid }}</pre>
<pre>{{ formulario.value | json}}</pre>

Comment: Para almacenar la fecha envio a la DB directamente el valor que tengo almacenado en el formulario. Osea, con el error. Sé que podría manipular este valor antes de enviarlo, pero me parece que tiene que haber una forma de hacerlo directamente desde el DateTimePicker. Si no encuento solución directa tendre que manipular el formulario antes de enviarlo.

Comment: Y cuando hablo del formulario me refiero al reactive, osea a:     this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
      CODIGO:    [ null ],
      NOME:      [ '',   Validators.required],
      DATA:      [ null, Validators.required],
      TIPO:      [ null, Validators.required],
      ELECTOS:   [ null, Validators.required],
      ACTIVO:    [ false ]
    });

Answer (score 0):

El MatDatepicker trabaja con moment para colocar un valor por defaul debes enviar el siguiente la fechas en el siguiente formato:

"2020-07-13T00:00:00-05:00".

Para obtener ese formtato utilizo el siguiente código.

```
public setDate(date) {
    return moment(date).format();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Para resolverlo puede concatenarle a la fecha la hora 0 por ejemplo

let fechaDate =  new Date(fecha + ' 0:00:00');

Luego utiliza la fechaDate en el formulario:

this.type.controls['fechaformulario'].setValue(fechaDate);